# How to get a warning on an unawaited task from non async code

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

If I forget to await a Task returned from an async method from in non async method I don't get a warning. This has resulted in several undiscovered bugs in my code due to unobserved exceptions.

I do get a warning if the calling method is async, but would like the same thing for when the calling method is non async.

I understand that you can't await from a non async method, the fix is to make the calling method async and then await it. But I would like a warning letting me know I should do this.

Is there a way to get the c# compiler to generate a warning in this case?

[image: missing warning on unawaited task]

Comment: Based on some quick Googling, I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058) will help you if you want to be advised whenever you discard the value returned by a method, and I think [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#MustUseReturnValueAttribute) will help you for one specific method.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for your links, see my answer below for a more specific solution using a roslyn analyzer which doesn't require resharper.

Comment: I don't even know what resharper is, which is why that wasn't an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The Mirosoft.VisualStudio.Threading roslyn analyzer produces warnings for these cases:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers

It produces the following warning:

> warning VSTHRD110: Observe the awaitable result of this method call by awaiting it, assigning to a variable, or passing it to another
> method

This can be included in your project by adding the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" Version="17.5.22">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

If using vs4mac you may need to clean and rebuild to get the warning to start working.